# Python: Printing out list when I dont want to

Tags: python

I made a list of functions and want to randomly select one for a trivia game, it keeps printing out the functions of my list.(I already defined functions)

def NBAquestions():
    x = 0
    question6 = Question("What does the NBA stand for?", "National Basketball Live", "National Fun Live", "National Basketball League",
                         "Nothin But Liberals", 3)
    if question6.ask() == True:
        print("You are correct")
        x += 1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        x -= 1

```
question7 = Question("What team won the championship last year (2016)?", "Golden State Warriors", "Miami Heat", "Minnesota Wild",
                     "Clevland Caviliers", 1)
if question7.ask() == True:
    print("You are correct")
    x += 1
else:
    print("incorrect")
    x -= 1

question8 = Question("What doesn't belong?", "Stephen Curry", "Kevin Durant", "Draymond Green",
                     "Mitch Marner", 4)
if question8.ask() == True:
    print("You are correct")
    x += 1
else:
    print("incorrect")
    x -= 1

question9 = Question("Is the Seattle Supersonics a current NBA team", "True", "False", "-",
                     "-", 2)
if question9.ask() == True:
    print("You are correct")
    x += 1
else:
    print("incorrect")
    x -= 1

question10 = Question("Micheal who?", "Jackson", "Johnson", "Jordan",
                     "Jarret", 3)
if question10.ask() == True:
    print("You are correct")
    x += 1
else:
    print("incorrect")
    x -= 1


print('Welcome to the Sports Trivia Game, you will compete head to head in a tivia matchup. One point will be awarded for getting 1 question right, but if you get 1 wrong you will lose a point')
a = input("please enter player 1's name: ")
b = input("please enter player 2's name: ")


questionList = ([NBAquestions(), MLBquestions(), NHLquestions(), NFLquestions()]
```

Comment: we can't solve it if we don't know the functions' definitions

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: def NBAquestions():
    x = 0
    question6 = Question("What does the NBA stand for?", "National Basketball Live", "National Fun Live", "National Basketball League",
                         "Nothin But Liberals", 3)
    if question6.ask() == True:
        print("You are correct")
        x += 1

Comment: wont let me print all of it out but here is the first statement in one of them

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting question in comments.

Comment: What functions are you talking about!? I see no functions. I see only calling functions.

Comment: at max characters but I have 3 other functions like this, I want to assign a set of questions to players but it prints them out before I can do that

Comment: The line `questionList = ([NBAquestions(), MLBquestions(), NHLquestions(), NFLquestions()]`  calls each function. You can use strings instead of calling functions like `questionList = (["NBAquestions", "MLBquestions", "NHLquestions", "NFLquestions"]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function with a random number and use a flag to finish the game.

```
from random import randint            # Generate random integers between 0 and 3 
randomNum = (randint(0, 3))           # 0 1 2 3

while True:
     if randomNum == 0:
            NBAquestions()
     elif randomNum == 1:
            MLBquestions()
     elif randomNum == 2:
            NHLquestions()
     elif randomNum == 3:
            NFLquestions()

     # Condition-flag indicate Game Over
     # You have to declare your global variable inside your functions
     # And when you have to end the game, set it True
     global flag 
     if flag == True:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you, still new to programming this helps a lot